# node js api return the response twise

Tags: node.js, rest

Hi am new to node js api

my program return data with twise like below 
i don't know what mistake i was made

it just return all rows from the table from mssql database.

**recordsets & recordset**

```
exports.getList = function (req, resp) {
    db.executeSql("SELECT * FROM OfficeDetails", function (data,err) {
        if (err) {
            httpMsgs.show500(req, resp, err);
        } else {
            console.log("response data " + JSON.stringify(data));
            httpMsgs.sendJson(req, resp, data);
           }
    });
};

{
    "recordsets": [
        [
            {
                "DeptName": "Software",
                "DeptId": 3
            },
            {
                "DeptName": "Sales",
                "DeptId": 1
            }
        ]
    ],
    "recordset": [
        {
            "DeptName": "Software",
            "DeptId": 3
        },
        {
            "DeptName": "Sales",
            "DeptId": 1
        }
    ],
    "output": {},
    "rowsAffected": [
        2
    ]
}
```

Comment: when is getList function called ? Can you add that piece of code ?

Comment: Also execute the above query in the SQL console or IDE and check what you are getting from DB

Comment: Add `httpMsgs.sendJson` code, 99% the problem is there.

Comment: exports.sendJson = function (req, resp, data) {
    resp.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "application/json" });
    if (data) {

        resp.write(JSON.stringify(data));
    }
    resp.end();
}


this is what i did

Comment: @MahendranB Can you post the result of the query after running it on shell or workbench?

Answer (score 0):

```js
exports.getList = function (req, resp) {
    db.executeSql("SELECT * FROM OfficeDetails GROUP BY DeptId HAVING COUNT(DeptId )>1", function (data,err) {
        if (err) {
            httpMsgs.show500(req, resp, err);
        } else {
            console.log("response data " + JSON.stringify(data));
            httpMsgs.sendJson(req, resp, data);
           }
    });
};
```

try this